# Quality Settings levels doesn't impact the UI elements

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm changing quality settings through code i.e. from High to Low. These settings are applied correctly to textures in the game but fails to impact any of the UI elements present within a canvas. Is there any way I can set them too according to the selected quality level?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess quality settings don´t affect ui elements in a canvas.  maybe you can achieve it by reducing the resolution of the canvas.

Comment: Doesn't this change sizes and positions of UI elements?